# Collection view inside a cell sometimes confuses your data

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a table that in each cell contains a `colectionView`. The table works correctly and it sends to each row an array that should mount the `collectionView`. The problem is that when I scroll the screen the last `collectionView` takes the data from the first `collectionView` that is in the first cell of the table.

This is the code in my table:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BSCCell", for: indexPath) as! BSCCell

        let itemsArray = dataArray[indexPath.section].object(forKey: "items") as! NSArray
        cell.items = itemsArray
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let itemsArray = dataArray[section].object(forKey: "items") as? NSArray

        if itemsArray!.count > 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let itemsArray = dataArray[indexPath.section].object(forKey: "items") as? NSArray
        let numberOfLines = ((itemsArray!.count) % 2 == 0 ? itemsArray!.count : Int(itemsArray!.count + 1)) / 2
        let totalHeight:CGFloat = CGFloat(numberOfLines * 120)

        return totalHeight
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = BIBlue()

        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 8.0, y: 10.0, width: self.view.frame.width - 50, height: 20.0)
        titleLabel.text = dataArray[section].object(forKey: "title") as? String
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name:"SegoeUI-Semilight", size: 15)
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        let separator = UIView()
        separator.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.width, height: 2.0)
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(separator)

        return view
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }
```

This is the code for my `collectionView`:

```
 var items:NSArray = []

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collView.delegate = self
        collView.dataSource = self
        collView.register(UINib(nibName: "BSCColl", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BSCColl")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        items = []
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
        return CGSize(width: (self.collView.frame.size.width / 2) - 4, height: 110)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let param = items[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
        let indicator = param?.object(forKey: "IdIndicador") as? String

        let notificationName = Notification.Name("bscNotification")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil, userInfo:["id":indicator!])
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BSCColl", for: indexPath) as! BSCColl
        let param = items[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
        cell.title.text = param?.object(forKey: "Parametro") as! String?
        cell.value.text = param?.object(forKey: "ValorCorrente") as! String?
        cell.diferenceValue.text = param?.object(forKey: "ValorPadrao") as! String?
        cell.metric.text = param?.object(forKey: "Metrica") as! String?

        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForRowAt indexPath:`, tell the `UICollectionView` to reload:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BSCCell", for: indexPath) as! BSCCell
    let itemsArray = dataArray[indexPath.section].object(forKey: "items") as! NSArray
    cell.items = itemsArray

    cell.collectionView.reloadData() // replace collectionView with the actual name you are using

    return cell
}
```

Alternatively, you can trigger reloading as a side effect when setting `items`. In your `UITableViewCell`s implementation:

```
var items = [Any] {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData() // replace collectionView with the actual name you are using
    }
}
```